# Remove lunch time from Total Time in Access.

Tags: ms-access

I am doing a datediff in an access field that I now need to also remove a 50 minute lunch break from.  Everything I have tried has created crazy numbers.  This is the function that works correctly without removing the lunch break:

```
=(DateDiff("n",[DispatchTime],[ReturnTime]))\60 & Format((DateDiff("n",[DispatchTime],[ReturnTime])) Mod 60,"\:00")
```

Then I try:

```
=(DateDiff("n",[DispatchTime],[ReturnTime]-.5))\60 & Format((DateDiff("n",[DispatchTime],[ReturnTime]-.5)) Mod 60,"\:00")
```

How can I do this? and still show in h:mm format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should suffice:

```
=Format(DateAdd("n",-50,[ReturnTime])-[DispatchTime],"h:nn")
```

Answer (score 0):

Return Time - .5 will remove 1/2 a day e.g.12 hours.

DateAdd ("n",-50, [YourDatefield]) will subtract 50 minutes.